# Spark: How to make spark execute transformation one time on which three actions depending on

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

We have written a spark batch application (Spark version: 2.3.0). Code is as below.

**Transformation:** `Dataset<CollectionFlattenedData> collectionDataDS =  flatMap`(Function which parse some files and return us the data set); This data set will have three types of data which are differentiated by column record type: 1,2,3.

**Load to Temp table** : `collectionDataDS.createOrReplaceTempView(TEMP_TABLE);` Creating temp view of dataset.

**Action1**: `sparkSession.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE recordtype='1'");` hive query to load TABLE1 table from temp table.

**Action2**: `sparkSession.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT COL4,COL5,COL6 FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE recordtype='2'");` Hive query to load TABLE2 from temp table.

**Action3**: `sparkSession.sql("INSERT INTO TABLE2 SELECT COL7,COL8,COL9 FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE recordtype='3'");` hive query to load ERROR table

What is happening: Because we are running 3 queries which are nothing but separate actions flatmap transformation is called three times(one time for one action). But our requirement is we should call flatmap operation only once.

CollectionFlattenedData pojo code is something like this

```
public class CollectionFlattenedData implements Serializable {

private String recordtype;

private String COL1;
private String COL2;
private String COL3;
private String COL4;
private String COL5;
private String COL6;
private String COL7;
private String COL8;
private String COL9;

//getters and setters of all the columns

}
```

Is there anyway we can do this. Early response is highly appreciated.

Comment: if you do cache dataset collectionDataDS then next two actions will not perform transformation again.

Comment: @RamdevSharma: Thanks for the reply it worked for us. I used persist instead of cache

Answer (score 1):

We can process this in two ways but first identify the size of the "TEMP_TABLE".

If the size is in the order of your RAM i.e. if it is able to cache good amount of your TEMP table, then you can cache it & use it in the further calculations.(You can get the data quantity from UI)

The other way better way is just save the data into a permanent table. 
You can just refer the next steps as usually.

When you use `.createOrReplaceTempView()`, you are giving a name to use it further in your spark sql like queries. It will not create any action on the resultant dataframe.